# Ubuntu 13.10 TTY wont open

Tags: command-line, tty

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I am trying to open a TTY screen, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-F6</kbd>, the only thing that happens is the mouse cursor disappears, nothing else no black screen. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, I get the cursor back.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I've run vbeinfo from the grub command-prompt. In my case, I'm running Ubuntu Server within VMware Workstation AND I'm interested in 800x600 and vbeinfo shows that 800x600x32 is available. So, I edit /etc/default/grub thus

GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600

save it, run 'sudo update-grub' and 'sudo reboot'. The Grub portion of the loader changes to 800x600, but quickly reverts to 640x480 as Ubuntu Server starts up.